# How to implement this pattern in C++?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have a class `UDPSocketTest`, which is derived from `SocketTest`. The `SocketTest` need an parameter in it's constructor.

Because of using the `gtest` framework, `UDPSocketTest` need to have an constructor without parameter, So I'd like to create it in constructor of `UDPSocketTest`, and pass it to `SocketTest`.

The problem is the base class is initialized before the member by C++ standard.

```
class UDPSocketTest : public SocketTest
{               
public:         
   UDPSocketTest()
      socketPool_(new SocketPool()),  <<---- Line 1
      SocketTest(socketPool_) {       <<---- Line 2
   }                         

   ~UDPSocketTest() {
   }           

private:
   SocketPool* socketPool_;
};
```

But the Line 2 should be called before Line 1. So any way to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a delegating constructor (C++11):

```
class UDPSocketTest : public SocketTest
{               
public:         
   UDPSocketTest() : UDPSocketTest(new SocketPool()) {}

   // You should already have this constructor written:
   UDPSocketTest(SockerPool *p)
      SocketTest(p),
      socketPool_(p)
   {
   }                         

   ~UDPSocketTest() {
   }           

private:
   SocketPool* socketPool_;
};
```

That's the path of least resistance. Before C++11, you'll have to move socketPool_ into a base class that's inherited from first, and thusly it will be the first one in the initialization order.